# Setting back button when presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

On clicking a button I display a view controller using the following code:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: locationVC)
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = StyleHelper.navBarColor()
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()               
navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), style: .Plain, target: locationVC, action: nil)
self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But the back button does not appear on the locationVC

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: did you write self.navigationController.navigationBar.ishidden = false in your next viewcontroller ?

Comment: @Amogh Shettigar I guess you need to push a controller on stack to get back button.

Comment: that's a normal behaviour. locationVC is the first and only controller, there is no previous page, that's why back button does not appear. If you are creating a new navigation controller everytime when presenting a new page, you are wrong. Try [pushViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc) instead of `presentViewController`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple issues with code.

**Issue 1:**

You should update viewController's bar button item and not navigationController's bar button item.

So this is wrong

```
navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

Whats correct

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

**Issue 2:**

The above code won't work because your current viewController is not pushed by any other VC so it cant show back button. What you need is `leftBarButtonItem`

So in your VC you can write

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Abcd", style: .done, target: self, action: yourSelectorHere)
}
```

**O/P:**

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed info, this was in fact the problem.

Comment: @amogh-shettigar : Always welcome buddy :) Am glad I could be of some help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 5):

Back button only appears for view controllers in the navigation stack.

you creating new navigation controller stack and making locationVC as root controller so there won't be any view controller to go back.

If you push another view controller to the navigation stack then you will get back button.

Answer (score 3):

> In a horizontally regular environment, the view controller is
>   presented in the style specified by the modalPresentationStyle
>   property. In a horizontally compact environment, the view controller
>   is presented full screen by default. [doc: presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller)

So, if you use present a view controller it will not show in navigation controller thus no back button 
For this case you need to push view controller.

**From storyboard:**

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "newViewController") as! YourViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Programmatically**

```
let vc = YourViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller is presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal.

If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

If you want to retain a reference to the view controller's presented view controller, get the value in the `presentedViewController` property before calling this method.

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

**More:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Answer (score 0):

presenting will present your VC on top of everything and not push it to the navigayionCOntroller.

You should push your VC to the NavigationController instead like so:

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profile") as ProfileViewController
    rootViewController.pushToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`presentViewController` is a method that bring a modal view to your navigation, not part of the `navigationController`.

Instead you should use the `pushToViewController` method on the `navigationController` (and not creating a new one) like that :

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
    navigationController.pushViewController(locationVC, animated: true)
}
```